# How to detect the size and name of USB drives in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

After using NSWorkSpace to detect how many USB drives I have, I still want to know the size and the name of the specific drive. How to get those information? I tried to use NSFileSystemSize, but seems the size I got is not the total size of the drive. It maybe just one of file size in that drive. Does someone know it?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the volume size, obtain the volume path as a URL, then use `-getResourceValue:forKey:error:` with `NSURLVolumeTotalCapacityKey` as the key.

```
NSError *error;
NSNumber *volumeSize;
if([volumeURL getResourceValue:&volumeSize
                        forKey:NSURLVolumeTotalCapacityKey
                         error:&error])
{
  NSLog(@"Volume size in bytes: %@", volumeSize);
}
else
{
  /* Handle error */
}
```

Other volume properties (including the name) can be obtained by using the right keys; the [list of valid keys is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html).